# SQLAlchemy model search with JOIN and OR

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

Having an issue getting some filtered results from a couple of joined tables.  Hoping you all can set me straight before I pull out what little hair I have left...  The query I need to run is something like this:

***Get all from Notifications where comm_approval != New, OR Notifications.rel_tas.startdate >= Today***

```
class Taskinfo(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'taskinfo'  
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    tasnum = db.Column(db.String(30), unique=False)
    startdate = db.Column(db.TIMESTAMP)
    enddate = db.Column(db.TIMESTAMP)

class Notifications(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'notifications'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    comm_approval = db.Column(db.String(30), unique=False, default='New')
    rel_tas_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('taskinfo.id'), nullable=False)
    rel_tas = db.relationship('Taskinfo', lazy='joined', foreign_keys=[rel_tas_id])
```

I've gotten this far, but for some reason this gives me back the results you'd expect from an AND

```
upQuery = db.session.query(Notifications) \
.join(Notifications.rel_tas).filter(or_(Notifications.comm_approval != 'New', Taskinfo.startdate >= datetime.utcnow())) \
.paginate(uppage,per_page,error_out=False)
```

***EDIT***
Something about this whole filter strikes me as wrong.  I just realized that in the prod system, this query would return 100's of thousands of lines.  Kinda much for a webpage.  I'm going to check with the customer on Monday.  Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
upQuery = db.session.query(Notifications) \
.join(Notifications.rel_tas).filter((Notifications.comm_approval != 'New') | (Taskinfo.startdate >= datetime.utcnow())) \
.paginate(uppage,per_page,error_out=False)
```

Comment: I hadn't, no.  But it seems to be returning the same results as my query?!?

Comment: It is the exact same query, just using the binary-or operator overload.